# PMTiles styling vs MBTiles styling

Tags: style

I made a test in which the Martin Tile Server serves a PMTile file through HTTP.
I can use a predefined style but I don't understand what is the usual process to build a style, why there are differences between PMTiles and MBTiles styling, and where are the official documentations about styling.

### 1st Attempt

1. I downloaded a file from https://maps.protomaps.com/builds/ (I didn't try the x-ray or map links, I don't know what it is)
   [image: protomaps download]
2. I extracted the Belgium area using the [pmtiles extract](https://docs.protomaps.com/pmtiles/cli#extract) command
3. I generated the layers cloning the [protomaps/basemaps](https://github.com/protomaps/basemaps/tree/main/styles), and then ran

```sh
pnpm run generate-layers protomaps light >> layers.json
```

[You can check the style.json here](https://file.io/HgnkrZSZ5FpH)

4. In the frontend code, I installed the `pmtiles` package and loaded the map using `MapLibre` like below:

```js
import { Protocol } from 'pmtiles';

const map = new maplibregl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: "osmstyle.json",
            center: [4.3601755242029885, 50.85819161299564], // brussels Lng / Lat
            zoom: 7 // starting zoom
        });

        let protocol = new Protocol();
        maplibregl.addProtocol('pmtiles', protocol.tile);
```

#### Result

[image: Brussels zoomed out]

### 2nd Attempt generating the `PMTiles` straight from `planetiler`

1. I then just generated the map using the `--output` of the `planetiler` tool
2. Then, I used the same layers as with the MBTiles test and I got the same nice map I got in the 1st test.
3. The map is great even if I get the same missing icons in the console, but I didn't get any HTTP error when zooming in.

[image: brussels zoomed out]

### Questions

Do you know why pmtiles or mptiles are using different styling specifications (or different source layer names)?

- For pmtiles, I've only found this [style guide page under
  construction](https://docs.protomaps.com/basemaps/layers). Hopefully,
  this repo https://github.com/protomaps/basemaps/tree/main/styles`
  helped me out but I don't have a hand on customization.
- For mbtiles, it seems to follow the [OSM Wiki page about features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features) and the [MapLibre Style Specs](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An attempt to answer

### Some abstracts

What you see in both cases is a combination of Mapbox/Maplibre GL styles and vector tiles. The image you see in the browser is generated by the style that says which sources (pmtiles/mbtiles) need to be called. The vector tiles comes either:

- from a pmtiles source that does not need a specific server (it access tiles through http range requests or optionally also via a server for compatibility)
- from a MBtiles where you need a server to serve pregenerated tiles using a pattern from the client like [https://yourserver.yourdomain/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://yourserver.yourdomain/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf) or [https://yourserver.yourdomain/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt](https://yourserver.yourdomain/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.mvt).

Consider pmtiles or mbtiles as a self-contained database with a structure of different tables with spatial representation and attributes for different zooms levels.

### Schemas differences in tiles source

The why you do not see the same result in both cases you choose is that while Planetiler generate tiles that match the OpenMapTiles Schema e.g https://openmaptiles.org/schema/, a default "database" structure for your tiles, the tiles from https://maps.protomaps.com/builds/ use https://docs.protomaps.com/basemaps/layers_v2

That's why you can't reuse the style for both sources as each of them differs due to layers available differences.

In both cases, the style used is by default [Maplibre GL JS styles](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/) as long as you use Maplibre as a client. In https://github.com/protomaps/basemaps/blob/main/README.md, you see the mention *"A TypeScript package that generates MapLibre GL styles, in multiple color themes, that can be used via npm or exported as JSON."* (another story for Leaflet https://docs.protomaps.com/pmtiles/leaflet and OpenLayers https://docs.protomaps.com/pmtiles/openlayers)

So at the end, you get two way to access vector tiles either pmtiles directly or mbtiles through a server. You declare style using Maplibre GL JS and you are good to go. If for instance, I use a pmtiles I convert to mbtiles, the only difference will be to replace the source and load a tiny lib to manage access to pmtiles in JavaScript e.g https://docs.protomaps.com/pmtiles/maplibre

### To compare both tiles sources structure mentioned

I use [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) utility to better see the JSON content

Get the file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdal_cp.py and with gdal 3.8 you will be able to get metadata info from pmtiles e.g

```bash
# Got URL from https://maps.protomaps.com/builds/
python gdal_cp.py "/vsipmtiles//vsicurl/https://build.protomaps.com/20240327.pmtiles/metadata.json" /vsistdout/ | jq .vector_layers
```

Access the metadata stored in mbtiles (exposed as json via `tileserver-gl`, a server to serve mbtiles)

```bash
# Example based on a public vector tiles service only available for France that use OpenMapTiles schema
curl https://openmaptiles.geo.data.gouv.fr/data/france-vector.json | jq .vector_layers
```

### Some practice to understand in a nutshell

To play, you can use sample from https://github.com/protomaps/PMTiles/blob/master/js/examples/maplibre.html#L24 combined with https://protomaps.github.io/PMTiles/protomaps(vector)ODbL_firenze.pmtiles

Then use the same pmtiles served using CLI utility https://github.com/protomaps/go-pmtiles?tab=readme-ov-file#serving-zxy-tiles (the same pattern you get from a normal mbtiles except here it's a pmtiles that is served) and change the source in https://github.com/protomaps/PMTiles/blob/master/js/examples/maplibre.html from `"pmtiles://" + PMTILES_URL` to `http://localhost:8080/protomaps(vector)ODbL_firenze.pmtiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt`